# In flask, why request header is None in app.before_request()?

Tags: python, flask, jwt

When I try to access the header of a request in a function adnotated with @app.before_request, it is always None. Anyone had this problem before?
Here is the function:

```
@app.before_request
def verifyToken():
    if request.endpoint in ['myEndpoint']
        auth = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        if auth.startswith('Bearer '):
            jwtToken = auth[7:]

            try:
                decoded = jwt.decode(jwtToken, 'secret_key', algorithms=['HS256'])
            except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError as e:
                responseObject = {
                "status": "failed",
                "message": "Token has expired. Please login again."
                }
                return jsonify(responseObject), 401
```

Comment: Have you tried returning just a simple "hello world" to make sure that the problem is not in the code?

Comment: I just find out that if I add this: if request.method != 'OPTIONS': then it works... but it's a bit strange

Answer (score 2):

I was being 5 months in `Flask`, I discover Flask Embeded Middleware fires up 2 times, the first one got None value and the second one is the client request and each fire up has different `request.method`, the `OPTIONS` and `<DEFAULT METHOD>` of the client, why there is an `OPTIONS` method first in `before...request` and `after...request` befoe goes in client request?, I'm still searching for reference

and that is why I just catch it through conditional statement `if request.method != 'OPTIONS':` and here how it is look like

```py
from flask import request

def my_before_request():
  if request.method !== 'OPTIONS'
    token = request.headers['<header var>']
    # do something...

# same as after request
```

Answer (score 0):

The OPTIONS method could have been triggered by the browser due to request being preflighted. This is done to determine if the actual request is safe to send. Refer [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests)